# Apple TestFlight feedback RSS

Tags: ios, testflight

We can use https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=/page=1/sortBy=mostRecent/xml
to subscribe feedbacks from App Store Review, but is there any way I can subscribe to feedbacks from TestFlight? Or is there any other alternatives so I can get notified at the first place when TestFlight user reports something to my app? Thanks.